# Can I select column values both separately and as one concatenation in the same query and avoid redundant code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, concatenation

I have a scenario in which I need to query values for an SSRS report and display them each once in their separate state and once all concatenated together. To avoid making future changes to the SSRS report, I want the concatenation to be done in the query. However, my current query has quite a bit of redundant code, as I have repeated the operations I perform on each of the columns inside the CONCAT() function:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
        THEN LEFT(a.TwoPartColumn, CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn) - 1)
        ELSE a.TwoPartColumn
    END AS FirstPart,
    CASE
        WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
        THEN RIGHT(a.TwoPartColumn, LEN(a.TwoPartColumn) - CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn))
        ELSE '001'
    END AS SecondPart,
    LEFT(rtrim(b.RightPadThis) + '0000000000', 10) AS RightPadded,
    RIGHT('00000000'+ rtrim(b.LeftPadThis,0), 8) AS LeftPadded,
    b.Units AS Units,
    CONCAT
    (
        CASE
            WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
            THEN LEFT(a.TwoPartColumn, CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn) - 1)
            ELSE a.TwoPartColumn
        END,
        CASE
            WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
            THEN RIGHT(a.TwoPartColumn, LEN(a.TwoPartColumn) - CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn))
            ELSE '001'
        END,
        LEFT(rtrim(b.ItemCd) + '0000000000', 10),
        RIGHT('00000000'+ rtrim(b.LeftPadThis,0))), 8),
        b.Units
    ) AS Concatenated
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b ON b.Id = a.Id
WHERE b.Param = @Param
```

Being a SQL novice, I tried passing the the columns' aliases into the CONCAT() function, to no avail.

While this query does achieve what I'm after, I want to know if I could clean it up or restructure it to avoid such redundant code.

Comment: Which sql version you are using because concat() will not work below 2012 version

Comment: Gimme a C! Gimme a T! Gimme an E! What's that spell? [Common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)! OK, that's not as catchy as it could be, but a CTE is still the most convenient way to compute some columns before selecting on them.

Comment: You can't use the alias of a column within the same `SELECT` clause, no. If you want to reference the alias of a column you have to either use a subquery or a CTE. For example `SELECT 1 AS one, one + 2 AS three;` would fail, however `SELECT one, one + 2 AS Three FROM (SELECT 1 AS one);` would work, [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: @Ramji I'm using SQL Server 2012. Functionality isn't currently an issue for me - the code sample I have in my post works, I just want to make it cleaner.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is also a neat way to alias expression results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a CTE is the most simple way to deal with this kind of thing. Something like this.

```
with MyData as
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
            THEN LEFT(a.TwoPartColumn, CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn) - 1)
            ELSE a.TwoPartColumn
        END AS FirstPart,
        CASE
            WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
            THEN RIGHT(a.TwoPartColumn, LEN(a.TwoPartColumn) - CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn))
            ELSE '001'
        END AS SecondPart,
        LEFT(rtrim(b.RightPadThis) + '0000000000', 10) AS RightPadded,
        RIGHT('00000000'+ rtrim(b.LeftPadThis,0), 8) AS LeftPadded,
        b.Units AS Units
    FROM TableA AS a
    JOIN TableB AS b ON b.Id = a.Id
    WHERE b.Param = @Param
)
select FirstPart
    , SecondPart
    , RightPadded
    , LeftPadded
    , Units
    , concat(FirstPart, SecondPart, RightPadded, LeftPadded, Units)
from MyData
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: This approach seems a little more readable to me. I like it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT
    part.FirstPart,
    part.SecondPart,
    LEFT(rtrim(b.RightPadThis) + '0000000000', 10) AS RightPadded,
    RIGHT('00000000'+ rtrim(b.LeftPadThis,0), 8) AS LeftPadded,
    b.Units AS Units,
    CONCAT
    (
        part.FirstPart,part.SecondPart,
        LEFT(rtrim(b.ItemCd) + '0000000000', 10),
        RIGHT('00000000'+ rtrim(b.LeftPadThis,0))), 8),
        b.Units
    ) AS Concatenated
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b ON b.Id = a.Id
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT CASE
        WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
        THEN LEFT(a.TwoPartColumn, CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn) - 1)
        ELSE a.TwoPartColumn
    END AS FirstPart,
    CASE
        WHEN a.TwoPartColumn LIKE '%-%'
        THEN RIGHT(a.TwoPartColumn, LEN(a.TwoPartColumn) - CHARINDEX('-', a.TwoPartColumn))
        ELSE '001'
    END AS SecondPart) part
)
WHERE b.Param = @Param
```

You can use the same technique for the other repeated expressions